# How to edit forms generated by FormSet that is generated by modelformset_factory?

Tags: django

so I have this formset that I'm using in my template :

```
def manage_authors(request):
    AuthorFormSet = modelformset_factory(Produkt, fields=('nazwa','ilosc','minimum',),extra=0)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = AuthorFormSet(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()

    else:
        formset = AuthorFormSet()
    return render(request, 'manage_authors.html', {'formset': formset})
```

And I wish I could like to edit properties of fields that are generated in the html page, change max length, size, label. Now I'm just getting default fields, I know how to do it for predefined forms but what about this situation?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. What do you mean by "I'm just getting default fields"? And by "predefined forms"? Can you explain a bit better what you see and what you would expect to see?

Comment: Ok, sorry about that I'm not so fluent with English, especially technical side of it : If i create ModelForm by myself I have the option to override default fields like in here : [link[(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields) But how I can do that if I have forms generated by modelformset_factory? For example, i want to text fields on my forms to be shorter and don't have labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [documented here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform-factory-function), you can also pass your customised `ModelForm` (e.g. `ProduktForm`) to the `modelform-factory`:

```
AuthorFormSet = modelformset_factory(Produkt, form=ProduktForm, fields=('nazwa','ilosc','minimum',),extra=0)
```

Also, if you only need to customise things that can be customised using the `Meta` class of the `ModelForm`, you can do that directly in your formset_factory:

```
AuthorFormSet = modelformset_factory(Produkt, fields=('nazwa','ilosc','minimum',), extra=0,
    widgets={'nazwa': Textarea(max_length=20)},
    labels={'nazwa': 'custom label'})
```

Comment: Thenk you for answer. If i try your solution i get : "name 'Textarea' is not defined" error 'nazwa' is `nazwa = models.CharField(max_length=200)` any idea how to fix it?